# Adding a delay/ Thread.sleep

Tags: java

So I am making a basic clicker game in java. So far I have two upgrades and an image of a boss you have to fight. I want it so once you reach a certain amount of points the boss's image would disappear after 5 seconds and a JLabel would appear saying "You defeated "Boss name". But you hear something approaching". The problem I have is that once I get to the set amount of points the image of the boss doesn't disappear. Here is my code

```
    // The "Clicker" class.
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


    public class Clicker extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
    static int multiply = 1;//Multiplier
    static boolean x2 = false;//Multiplier bought or not boolean
    static boolean add10 = false;//+10 bought or not boolean
    static int score = 950;//Startingn points 0
    static JFrame j = new JFrame ("Clicker");
    JLabel l = new JLabel ("Points: " + String.valueOf (score));//Points Label
    static JLabel name = new JLabel ();//Name Label
    JTextField jt = new JTextField ("Name");//Name Text Box 
    JButton click = new JButton ();//+1 Button
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Clicker run = new Clicker ();//Object of class

    } // main method


    public Clicker () 
    {   
        JLabel boss1 = new JLabel ();//Boss Label

        JButton multiplier = new JButton ("x2(5000)");//X2 upgrade button

        JButton plus10 = new JButton ("+10(100 Points)");//+10 upgrade button

        JButton enter = new JButton ("Enter");//Enter name

        JPanel p = new JPanel ();//Main Pane

        JButton reset = new JButton ("Reset");//Reset Button

        multiplier.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()//X2 MULTIPLIER ACTION PERFORMED
                {
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                        if (score > 5000 || score == 5000)// If you have enough to buy upgrade
                        {
                            if (x2 == false)// If you did not previously but upgrade
                            {
                                score = score - 5000;//Subtract 5000 points
                                l.setText ("Points: " + score);//Redisplay Points
                                click.setVisible (false);
                                x2 = true;//Set true to show you bought upgrade
                            }

                        }
                        if (x2 == true)//If bought upgrade
                        {
                            multiply = 2;//Set multiplier by 2
                            multiplier.setVisible(false);//set boolean to true so they can't rebuy
                        }
                        else if (score < 5000)//If you dont have enough points
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You do not have enough points.", null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);//Dont have enough points message


                        }

                    }

                });

        plus10.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()//PLUS10 BUTTON ACTION PERFORM
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (score > 100 || score == 100)//If you have more than 100 points
                {
                    if (add10 == false)//For first time buy
                    {
                        score = score - 100;
                        l.setText ("Points: " + score);
                        click.setVisible (false);//Remove +1 button and replace with +10
                        Insets insets = p.getInsets ();

                        plus10.setBounds (75+ insets.left, 250 + insets.top, 150, 100);//Move +10 button to where the +1 button was
                        add10 = true;//Set true so it doesn't take 100 points off again
                    }

                }
                if (add10 == true)
                {
                    score = score + 10 * (multiply);//Adding 10
                    l.setText ("Points: " + score);//Redisplay score

                }
                else if (score < 100)//If score is less than 100
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You do not have enough points.", null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);//Dont have enough points for upgrade


                }

            }

        }
        );

        enter.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()//ENTER NAME ACTION PERFORMED
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                String input = jt.getText ();
                name.setText (input);
            }

        }
        );
        jt.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()//NAME TEXTBOX ACTION PERFORMED
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                String input = jt.getText ();
                name.setText (input);
            }

        }
        );
        reset.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()//RESET BUTTON ACTION PERFORMED
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                score = 0;
                l.setText ("Points: " + score);
            }

        }
        );

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////BOSS ATTACK
        int boss1health;
        boss1health = 1000;

        if(score >= boss1health){

            try{
                boss1.setVisible(false);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            JLabel boss1defeat = new JLabel ("You defeating MewTwo. But you see another threat approuching.");

        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////BOSS ATTACK

        ImageIcon boss1image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mewtwospirte.png") );
        boss1.setIcon(boss1image);//SETTING BOSS1 IMAGE TO MEWTWO

        ImageIcon cimage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("plus1.png") );//PLUS ONE IMAGE
        click.setIcon(cimage);//SETTING PLUS ONE IMAGE TO +1 CLICKER


      //Change Color
        name.setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        jt.setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        p.setBackground (Color.WHITE);
        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        click.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        j.getContentPane ().add (p);//ADD PANE TO JFRAME

        p.setLayout (null);//Set Pane to Absolute Layout

        Insets insets = p.getInsets ();//Basically Coordinates/Pixels of JFrame

        Dimension size = jt.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        jt.setBounds (0 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, 75, size.height);//Placing the function

        size = enter.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        enter.setBounds (75 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);//Placing the function

        size = click.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        click.setBounds (75+ insets.left, 250 + insets.top, 150, 100);//Placing the function

        size = reset.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        reset.setBounds (0 + insets.left, 370 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);//Placing the function

        size = name.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        name.setBounds (0 + insets.left, 20 + insets.top, 50, 50);//Placing the function

        size = l.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        l.setBounds (175 + insets.left, 30 + insets.top, 100, size.height);//Placing the function

        size = plus10.getPreferredSize ();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        plus10.setBounds (165 + insets.left, 370 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);//Placing the function

        size = multiplier.getPreferredSize();//Gets Size based off font, etc
        multiplier.setBounds(170 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);//Placing the function

        boss1.setBounds(75 + insets.left, 75 + insets.top, 175, 175);//Placing the function

        //ADDING ALL THE COMPONENETS/FUNCTIONS
        p.add(boss1);
        p.add(multiplier);
        p.add (plus10);
        p.add (jt);
        p.add (name);
        p.add (reset);
        p.add (l);
        p.add (click);
        p.add (enter);

        click.addActionListener (this);

        j.setResizable (false);//Set the JFrame to not be resizable
        j.setSize (300, 450);//Set JFrame Size
        j.setVisible (true);//Set JFrame to be visible
    }


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)//Action performed when clicking the +1 button
    {
        score = score + 1 * (multiply);
        l.setText ("Points: " + score);
    }        
}
```

I know that the I haven't added the JLabel that says the message after you defeat the boss. I wanted to solve the issue with the boss image becoming invisible first.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Your code example is far too long; please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried adding validate() and repaint() after you update the visibility?

Comment: I tried the new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){ but it gave me the error Cannot instantiate the type Handler(under Handler) and under postDelayed it gives the error "The method postDelayed(new Runnable(){}, int) is undefined for the type Handler"

Comment: I also tried adding validate() and repaint() but still doesn't work. Maybe it my if statement isn't being reached?

Comment: You could try revalidate() instead of valiadte and then repaint but to see if the 'if' statement is reached you will need to step through in the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(score >= boss1health){
    try{
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boss1.setVisible(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    JLabel boss1defeat = new JLabel ("You defeating MewTwo. But you see another threat approuching.");

}
```